# Infinite Loop while using react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning react for past few days and while using useEffect hook i'm getting infite loop over setting my state variable.

Can anyone tell me what's going on and how to overcome this [image]

Here's my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const TodoEntry = () => {

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/todos')
     .then(res => { setTodos(res.data); console.log(todos) })
     .catch(err => console.log(err))
  },[todos]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Todo App</h1>
   </div>
  );
};

export default TodoEntry;
```

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
    getTodos();
  },[todos]);` try this.

Comment: `useEffect(() => getTodos(), []);` since you only want to do this once, on mount. If you have a linter which throws an error, then you can wrap `getTodos` in a `useCallback` to memoize it (not create a new function reference every time we render) and add it back to the dependencies array, or put the `getTodos` code inside the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: @MichaelYaworski not a good idea to skip adding the dependencies in `useEffect` hook's dependency array

Comment: @Yousaf it's a good idea if you only want to do it on mount

Comment: @MichaelYaworski [Is it safe to omit functions from the list of dependencies?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies)

Comment: @Yousaf You're right if the code actually has dependencies. In this case, there are no actual dependencies and the request is meant to be run once. The third code snippet on the docs that you linked show an example of something similar. Technically `getTodos` is a dependency, but it's a faux one since it doesn't actually change. That's my take on it anyway.

Comment: I've tried your suggestions but still i got the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of problems in your code:

- Since `getTodos` function is a dependency of `useEffect` hook, every time state updates, new `getTodos` function is created which then triggers the `useEffect` hook.
- You don't need to chain `then` function when using `async-await` syntax. You can just await the result of `axios.get(...)`.

To fix the first problem of infinite loop, use one of the following options:

- Wrap the `getTodos` function in `useCallback` hook. For details, see [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

  Since, `getTodos` function calls `displayTodos`, you will need to wrap it in `useCallback` hook and add `displayTodos` in the dependency array of `useCallback` hook that wraps `getTodos` function. In my opinion, it is better to just remove the `displayTodos` function and update the state inside `getTodos` function

  ```
  const getTodos = useCallback(async () => {
     try {
        const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/todos')
        setTodos(res.data);
     } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
     }
  }, [setTodos]);
  ```

  #### Demo

  [image: Edit cold-darkness-xgjwp]
- Put the code inside `getTodos` inside `useEffect` hook and remove the `getTodos` function.

  ```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/todos")
     .then(res => setTodos(res.data))
     .catch(err => console.log(err));

  }, [setTodos]);
  ```

  #### Demo

  [image: Edit blissful-darkness-1q7ng]

Comment: Thank you Yousaf, I've tried the second method and got the correct result.

Comment: Note that is it safe to omit `setTodos` from the dependency array since it is a function from the `useState` hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

"React guarantees that `setState` function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the `useEffect` or `useCallback` dependency list."

Comment: @MichaelYaworski yes it is safe but still i don't mind adding it as a dependency because it keeps me in the habit of not missing the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

This is because the dependency list for your `useEffect` call is a function. You probably meant to add the todos data itself.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getTodos();
  },[todos]);
```